# Selector Context not always Valid?

Tags: jquery, selector, implementation

I have a block of code that goes like so:

```
function funcName() {
    if(isOverlap("#obj1", ".obj2") == true) {
        doThisFunc(".obj2");
    }
}

function isOverlap(obj1, obj1){
    //check to see if objects overlap, returns true if so
}

function doThisFunc(obj1){
    counter++;
    $(obj1, this).remove();
}
```

But this does not remove the specific instance of the class attempting to be removed, in fact it doesn't remove anything at all. Can you explain to me why the selector context is not valid in this situation and a way to remove only the one instance that is overlapping? Maybe using `.on()` and `.trigger()`? (I'm not very clear on what these do yet)

***EDIT:*** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/jh7LD/25/) is a link to the project. The if statement is found on line 157 of the JavaScript section. The "doThisFunc" is actually `getCoin(obj1)` found starting on line 180 of the same section. I tried to use Vega's remedy, but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: Can you post a complete code example, and if possible a jsFiddle?

Comment: Add `console.log(this);` inside your `doThisFunc` function. I suspect it won't be what you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` reference in `doThisFunc` function would be `window` object. You are not maintaining the context when calling the function. Use `.call` or `.apply` when calling the external function from the handler to maintain the context.

```
doThisFunc.call(this, ".obj2");
```

Comment: For reference: [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)